# View isn't updated using angular 2

Tags: html, angular, typescript

This is my navigation html

```
    <nav class="menu">
    <a href="/logout">Logout</a>
</nav>
<input  placeholder="SEARCH FOR SOLUTION..." type="text" class="search-input" [(ngModel)]="searchInput"
       (ngModelChange)="filter()"/>
```

This is my Navigation Component

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "angular2/core";
import {Output} from "angular2/core";
import {Input} from "angular2/core";
import {EventEmitter} from "angular2/core";
import {NgZone} from "angular2/core";

@Component({
    selector: "navigation",
    templateUrl: 'app/components/navigation/navigation.html'
})

export class NavigationComponent implements OnInit {
    @Output() onFilterSolutions = new EventEmitter<string>();

    public searchInput:string;

    constructor(private _ngZone:NgZone) {
        console.log("Great!");
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(222);
    }

    filter() {
        this.onFilterSolutions.emit(this.searchInput);

    }
}
```

The event is catch by this component (method: onFilterSolutions)

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "angular2/core";
import {Http, Headers} from "angular2/http";

import {SolutionComponent} from "../../shared/models/SolutionComponent";
import {SolutionComponentType} from "../../shared/models/SolutionComponentType";

import {SolutionsService} from "../../shared/services/SolutionsService";
import {MetaComponentsService} from "../../shared/services/MetaComponentsService";
import {Solution} from "../../shared/models/Solution";
import {ISolution} from "../../shared/interfaces/ISolution";
import {Input} from "angular2/core";
import {NavigationComponent} from "../navigation/NavigationComponent";
import {Output} from "angular2/core";
import {NgZone} from "angular2/core";

@Component({
    selector: "home",
    templateUrl: "app/components/home/home.html",
    directives: [NavigationComponent]
})


export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    cachedSolutions:Solution[] = [];
    solutions:Solution[] = [];
    metaComponents:any;


    constructor(public _solutionsService:SolutionsService, public _metaComponentsService:MetaComponentsService, private _ngZone: NgZone) {
        this._solutionsService.getAll().then((solutions) => {
            this._metaComponentsService.getAll().then((metaComponents) => {
                this.metaComponents = metaComponents;
                this.solutions = solutions;
                this.cachedSolutions = solutions;

            }, (err) => {
                console.error(err);
            });
        }, (err) => {
            console.error(err);
        });
    }

    public getMetaComponent(solution) {
        var metaComponent = this.metaComponents.find((metaComponentItem) => {
            return metaComponentItem._id === solution.metaComponentId;
        });

        return metaComponent;
    }

    public updateSolution(solution) {
        this._solutionsService.update(solution.toJSON()).then((response) => {
            console.log("Update Success");
        }, (err) => {
            alert("Error Updating Solution: " + solution._id);
        })
    }

    public onFilterSolutions(searchInput:string) {
        var self = this;

        this._ngZone.run(() => {
            self.solutions = !searchInput ? self.cachedSolutions : self.cachedSolutions.filter(function (solution) {
                var solutionNameSearch = (-1 !== solution.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchInput.toLowerCase()));
                var metaComponent = self.getMetaComponent(solution);


                if (metaComponent) {
                    return (-1 !== metaComponent.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchInput.toLowerCase())) || solutionNameSearch
                } else {
                    return solutionNameSearch;
                }

            });
        });

        console.log(this.solutions);
    }

    public addComponentType(changedSolution) {
        var solutionComponentType:SolutionComponentType = new SolutionComponentType({
            name: "Untitled",
            description: "Untitled",
            components: []
        });

        //noinspection TypeScriptUnresolvedVariable
        var sourceSolution:Solution = this.solutions.find((solution) => solution._id === changedSolution._id);

        sourceSolution.componentTypes.push(<SolutionComponentType>solutionComponentType.toJSON());

    }

    public addComponent(changedComponentType) {
        var component = new SolutionComponent({
            name:"Untitled",
            description:"Untitled",
            minCost:0,
            maxCost:0,
            isDefault:false
        })


        changedComponentType.components.push(component.toJSON());
    }

    ngOnInit():any {
        return undefined;
    }

}
```

When updating the solutions array the NgFor inside the html doesn't refresh.

This is the html output:

```
<div class="container">
    <navigation (onFilterSolutions)="onFilterSolutions($event)">
    </navigation>

    <ul class="solutions">
        <li class="solution" *ngFor="#solution of solutions">
            <h2 class="meta-component">
               <img  class="icon" src="http://studio.seebo.com/{{getMetaComponent(solution).icon}}" />{{ getMetaComponent(solution).name }}
            </h2>
            <input [(ngModel)]="solution.name" (ngModelChange)="updateSolution(solution)"/>
            <input class="description" placeholder="Solution Description" [(ngModel)]="solution.description" (ngModelChange)="updateSolution(solution)"/>
            <ul class="component-types">
                <li class="component-type" *ngFor="#componentType of solution.componentTypes">
                    <label>Component Type Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="componentType.name" (ngModelChange)="updateSolution(solution)"/>

                    <ul class="components">
                        <li class="component" *ngFor="#component of componentType.components">
                            <div>
                                <input type="text" class="full-width" [(ngModel)]="component.name"
                                       (ngModelChange)="updateSolution(solution)"/>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <label>Min Cost</label>
                                <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="component.minCost"
                                       (ngModelChange)="updateSolution(solution)"
                                step="0.1"/>
                                <label>Max Cost</label>
                                <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="component.maxCost"
                                       (ngModelChange)="updateSolution(solution)" step="0.1"/>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <button (click)="addComponent(componentType)">+</button>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button (click)="addComponentType(solution)">+</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Hope this is enough information, Thanks.

Comment: What is the expected behavior. What part of all this code isn't updated? After which action do you expect it to be updated?

Comment: The solutions property.

Comment: I think you should reduce your code. It contains a lot where I'm sure this is not related to the problem. Btw the downvote wan't me.

Comment: Well when calling onFilterSolution inside HomeComponent as you see i'm filtering the solutions array and expecting it's reflect into the view.

Comment: You don't need `var self = this;` when you use `=>` (arrow functions). Try `this.solutions = this.solutions.splice();` as last line inside `zone.run(...)`. You might not need `zone.run(...)` at all. Looks like you just tried to solve the problem  using `zone.run(...)`

Comment: Well the code work's correctly, the problem was inside the template, the function getMetaComponent was return undefined so everything was crashing, thanks.